# "fetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed" when using spacejam in meteor

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, graphql

I'm writing unit tests to check my api. Before I merged my `git` *test* branch with my *dev* branch everything was fine, but then I started to get this *error*:

```
App running at: http://localhost:4096/
spacejam: meteor is ready
spacejam: spawning phantomjs
phantomjs: Running tests at http://localhost:4096/local using test-in-console
phantomjs: Error: fetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed, to fix pass a fetch for
  your environment like https://www.npmjs.com/package/unfetch.

  For example:
    import fetch from 'unfetch';
    import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';

    const link = createHttpLink({ uri: '/graphql', fetch: fetch });
```

Here's a part of my `api.test.js` file:

```
describe('GraphQL API for users', () => {
    before(() => {
      StubCollections.add([Meteor.users]);
      StubCollections.stub();
    });

    after(() => {
      StubCollections.restore();
    });

    it('should do the work', () => {
      const x = 'hello';
      expect(x).to.be.a('string');
    });
  });
```

The funniest thing is that I don't even have `graphql` in my tests (although, I use it in my `meteor` package)
Unfortunately, I didn't to find enough information (apart from [apollo-link-http docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/http.html) that has examples, but still puzzles me). I did try to use that example, but it didn't help and I still get the same error

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/http.html#fetch

Answer (score 8):

If you're using nodejs do the following:

Install `node-fetch`

```
npm install --save node-fetch
```

Add the line below to `index.js`:

```
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error importing a npm module doing graphql queries into my React application. The app was compiling but tests were failing since `window.fetch` is not available in the Node.js runtime.

I solved the problem by installing `node-fetch` https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch and adding the following declarations to `jest.config.js`:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

global.fetch = fetch
global.window = global
global.Headers = fetch.Headers
global.Request = fetch.Request
global.Response = fetch.Response
global.location = { hostname: '' }
```

Doing so we instruct Jest on how to handle `window.fetch` when it executes frontend code in the Node.js runtime.

Comment: I used this to mock fetch which also resolved the errors https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this: `fetch` is defined when you are in the browser, and is available as `fetch`, or even `window.fetch`

In the server it is not defined, and either needs to be imported explicity, or a polyfill like https://www.npmjs.com/package/unfetch (as suggested in the error message) needs to be imported by your test code to make the problem go away.

Comment: Please confirm, so install ```unfetch``` (why the old thread says ```node-fetch```) and however, I am not sure how to ```import``` in test code (we use Jest, so probably adding in jest.config.js) - but can you please give an example?