# Htmlunit can't load all elements of site, because of js exception

Tags: java, exception, htmlunit

I'm creating some app using htmlunit library, but the problem is some very important pieces of site can't be loaded, because of javascript exception:

`net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.JavaScriptException: Error: fetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed, to fix pass a fetch for your environment like https://www.npmjs.com/package/unfetch.`

I've tried to use `client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);`, but it is not working. How to fix it?

Comment: P.S. I can't change code of the site itself

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154509/fetch-is-not-found-globally-and-no-fetcher-passed-when-using-spacejam-in-meteo

Comment: I've already seen it, but he is using javascript, I'm wirting in java with htmlunit library, have you got any idea how to implement this solution using java?

Answer (score 0):

As of HtlUnit version 2.30 the Fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is not supported/implemented. Please open an issue for HtmlUnit (and if you like provide a patch).

Because the Fetch API is not available in IE (as far a i know) maybe it is an option to use the IE simulation of HtmlUnit.

It will also be helpful to figure out which part of the api is used by the website. Then we can focus on implementing this stuff first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Headless Chrome, which supports the fetch API.

Download Chrome driver here : https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.38/

Or on macOS :

```
brew install chromedriver
```

Then add a recent version of Selenium in your pom.xml/graddle:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Of course you will need a Chrome version > 59

And here comes the Java part:

```
String chromeDriverPath = "/Path/To/Chromedriver" ;  
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);  
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");  
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I wrote a blog post with detailed instruction here : 
https://ksah.in/introduction-to-chrome-headless/